# How do I add an EFI partition to a fresh PC?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, lubuntu, calamares

I built a PC and was wondering, how in the world do I make an EFI partition?

Manual Partitioning is the only option shown.

(I'm using Lubuntu 20.04.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a EFI partition. If you booted the LiveUSB in UEFI mode and select to Install Ubuntu, the partition will be created automatically.

You can also chose "something else" and create all partitions you need including EFI manually.

Comment: Can also use Gparted from live USB and make what ever partitions you want before using install option.

Comment: I believe this is the case even with Calamares (which recent versions of Lubuntu, but not other official derivatives of Ubuntu, use instead of the Ubiquity installer). The installer should still be able to create all needed partitions automatically, for common situations, including having a disk with no EFI partition.